# How do I use the virtual numeric keypad/touchpad on an ASUS Zenbook UM?

Tags: touchpad, asus, numpad

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.10 on an ASUS 14 UM and everything is fine except for the virtual keyboard on the touchpad, which in Window $ is activated / deactivated on the touchpad itself, as well as its lighting. I have looked for information about it but I have not found solutions, apparently until last year they had not been given. The kernel is 5.8
I appreciate your help = /

*Translation adapted from Google Translate:*

> **Teclado numérico virtual en touchpad ASUS UM no funciona**
>
> Un saludo. Recién he instalado Ubuntu 20.10 en un ASUS 14 UM y todo va bien menos el teclado virtual en el touchpad, que en Window$ se activa/desactiva en el mismo touchpad, así como la iluminación del mismo. He buscado info al respecto pero no he encontrado soluciones, al parecer hasta el año pasado no se habían dado. El kernel es 5.8 Agradezco su ayuda =/

Answer (score 3):

You can install numpad driver for linux from  [here](https://github.com/asus-linux-drivers/asus-touchpad-numpad-driver)

Comment: Yes this driver works perfect on my Expertbook

Answer (score 0):

I maintain latest & most featured version of Asus numpad/touchpad driver. Link https://github.com/asus-linux-drivers/asus-touchpad-numpad-driver. If any problems persist, please contact me via github contact e-mail or create issue on github repository. If you use laptop Asus WMI hotkeys (Fn+Fx keys) or Asus accessories like stylus you might be interested in other drivers https://github.com/asus-linux-drivers, install them in the same way as numpad one.